# Why would an event listener in a JavaScript class see old context variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I'm having a problem that seems to defy everything I know about how scope is handled in JavaScript with anonymous functions - but it could be something else I'm not thinking about.

I have a JavaScript object, called Element, with a constructor similar to this:

```
function Element(boxElement) {
    var self = this;

    // Set jquery instance variables
    self.pageElement = null;
    self.boxElement  = boxElement;

    ... blah blah blah

    // Implement triggers to empty functions
    self.onElementClicked = function () {};

    // Bind listeners
    self._bind_listeners();
}
```

The bind_listeners method is defined as such

```
Element.prototype._bind_listeners = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.boxElement.on('click', function (e) {
        // Don't handle if handled already
        if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return;
        console.log("Got past the return");
        self.onElementClicked();
    });
};
```

And there's also a method to set the callback method onElementClicked:

```
Element.prototype.on_element_click = function(callback) {
    var self = this;
    self.onElementClicked = callback;
};
```

The problem I am encountering is that if I set my callback using the on_element_click method, my method doesn't see the current instance - it sees what the instance would look like just after construction.

More specifically to my situation, there's an instance variable called boxElement that refers to a JQuery element - and in Chrome's console I can see that the instance (self) still does refer to the correct element on the page, but the onElementClicked instance variable (and others) do not seem to be set from within the listener.

Feel free to revise my explanation or ask for clarification.

**From the implementer perspective:**

If I do this:

```
// Set default listener for element click
formElement.on_element_click(function () {
    console.log("Hello");
});
```

The listener never says Hello because onElementClicked doesn't appear to be set.

However, if I instead do this:

```
formElement.boxElement.click(function () {
    console.log("Hello");
});
```

It successfully says "Hello" and makes me confused.

Comment: Are you not failing to bind events to the `.boxElement` property instead of the `formElement` in your first example that's causing problems?

Comment: The first example is what I want to do. the boxElement variable is an instance variable that /should/ be private. The on_element_click method is supposed to store the callback and run it using its own listener for boxElement.click.

The reason I can't do it the 2nd way (aside from just good OO design) is because I might later override this callback method with a new one. (removing the old callback method intentionally)

Comment: Seems to work for me with plain elements and event listeners (not jQuery) https://jsfiddle.net/fpfofczy/ - not sure if this is similar to what you're doing.

Comment: It is not a click on "self". Refer to the implementation of on_element_click - the method sets a instance variable which holds the callback method called in the listener.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I realised I'd read it wrong just after I edited my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my specific problem, which is a good example of how an error like this can occur. (offtopic: please feel free to add answers for other ways to produce this error - it is a very non-intuitive problem and will always be caused by an external factor)

It turns out the class I was testing with is a class that *extends* my Element class - BUT, it does so improperly / VERY VERY badly!

As embarrassing as it is to post this, here's the original constructor of my "subclass" (quotes for reasons soon apparent):

```
function StrikeoutFormElement (formElement) {
    var self = this;

    // Set reference to form element
    self.fe = formElement;

    $.extend(self, self.fe);

    // Override methods
    self.on_reposition(function () {
        self._on_reposition();
    });
}
```

I used JQuery's object extending function and a hacky workaround to override something. I have learned the hard way to NEVER use JQuery's extend for OOP, as it is only intended for data manipulation rather than as a language tool.

The new constructor looks like this:

```
function StrikeoutFormElement (elem) {
    var self = this;

}
// Extend the FormElement prototype
StrikeoutFormElement.prototype = Object.create(Element.prototype);
StrikeoutFormElement.prototype.constructor = Element;
```

This is a method described in an MDN article somewhere. I'll post the source when I find it if someone doesn't beat me to it.

Shoutout to anyone who looked at this obscure problem and attempted to figure it out!

Comment: Was it this article? [Classes and Inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Contributor_s_Guide/Classes_and_Inheritance), if so feel free to to add it to your answer. And don't be to harsh on yourself, you simply learned something useful _and_ followed up on your question so you'll probably help others with similar problems.